# mysql_query return 0 element

Tags: mysql, foreach

I've this code that get all record from a MySql table and execute a switch stateform:

```
<?php

$DB_host = 'localhost';
$DB_user = 'user';
$DB_password = 'pwf';
$DB_name = 'dbname';
$connessione = mysql_connect($DB_host, $DB_user, $DB_password);
$db_obj = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`table`")or die("Query not valid: " . mysql_error());
$i = 0;
foreach ($db_obj as $dato) {
    $i++;
    switch ($dato->turno) {
        case 0:
            $desc = 'Mattina';
            $col = 'bg-color-redLight';
            break;
        case 1:
            $desc = 'Pomeriggio';
            $col = 'bg-color-greenLight';
            break;
        case 2:
            $desc = 'Notte';
            $col = 'bg-color-blueLight';
            break;
        case 3:
            $desc = 'Smonto Notte';
            $col = 'bg-color-yellow';
            break;
        case 4:
            $desc = 'Riposo';
            $col = 'bg-color-orange';
            break;
    }
}
?>
```

Why result that $db_obj is empy? In the table there are 3 records..
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not storing the result in anything suitable. Have a look at [**`mysql_fetch_array`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_Array)

```
$db_obj = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`table`")or die("Query not valid: " . mysql_error());
$i = 0;
while($datato = mysql_fetch_array($db_obj, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
  $i++;
  switch ($dato['turno']) { 
      //Cases
  }
}
```

`mysql_` is deprecated and it's advised to look into [**`mysqli`**](http://php.net/mysqli) or [**`pdo`**](http://php.net/pdo)

> **WARNING:** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [***MySQLi***](http://php.net/mysqli) or [***PDO_MySQL***](http://php.net/pdo)  extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
> mysqli_fetch_array()
> PDOStatement::fetch()

Comment: I have an error on this line..
foreach($dato=mysql_fetch_array($db_obj, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

Comment: Sorry, what should be a `while`!

Comment: @hd could I know how many record I have selected? If I do count($datato) it doesn't work..

Comment: Have a look at [**`mysql_num_rows`**](http://uk1.php.net/mysql_num_rows). Put that above the `while`. So; `$intTotalRows = mysql_num_rows($db_obj);`